# Create Dynamic Button Objects

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create `Button` objects in a dynamic way. I'm not really sure if this is possible. The following code has been used before (and failed):

```
    public class GraphManager{
        private Vector<Button> machineButtons = null;

        public Vector<Button> getMachineButtons(){
            return machineButtons;
        }
        public void setMachineButtons(int machines, Context context){
            for(int i = 0; i < machines; i++){
                Button machineButton = new Button(context);
                machineButtons.add(machineButton);
            }
        }
        public Button getMachineButton(int index){
            return machineButtons.elementAt(index);
        }
    }
```

Are there any solutions for my problem?

Comment: please post your logcat error

Comment: You forgot to initialize the Vector.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I should've spotted the initalization.